# PHP как прочитать json файл и вытащить нужные данные

Tags: php, json, json-encode

data.json

```
[{"login":99010},{"login":99011},{"login":99012}]
```

Как мне его получить превратить в массив и вывести на экран.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить данные из JSON, его надо раскодировать.

Для этого в РНР есть функция json_decode(). Для новичков удобнее использовать её, передав в качестве второго параметра true - в этом случае все структуры данных будут представлены в виде массивов.

То есть вопрос сведется к "**как получить данные из массива**". И ответ будет обычный - к отдельным элементам обращаться по индексу, а множественные перебирать через foreach

```
$json = '[{"login":99010},{"login":99011},{"login":99012}]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);   
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "логин: {$row['login']}<br>\n";
}
```

Если нужно получить из файла или стороннего сервиса, то используй

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
// или
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/data.json');
```